# IntelliJ IDEA: Show containing folder in 'project' sidebar.

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.6., and I'm trying to figure out how to make a file's parent folder show in the 'project' sidebar when I open it. I'm pretty sure I had it set up that way in the past, but I can't find the relevant setting. I've tried googling to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for `Navigate` | `Select In` or `Autoscroll from source` option?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes, it was Autoscroll from Source! In case anyone else is looking, it's under the gear icon in the project sidebar. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Autoscroll from source** option can be enabled under the gear icon in the [Project tool window](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project-tool-window.html).

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the Projects sidebar show the project's entire directory structure?

As an alternative, if you go to View -> Navigation Bar, you can see the selected file's path on the top left.

Comment: It does, but I was hoping to figure out how to have the specific parent folder highlighted, so I don't have to browse through the whole structure when I open a file, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

For those reading now, the suggestions here don't seem to be in the current version of intellij.

I had to go Right click on the folder -> Open Module Settings -> remove the obviously incorrect content root -> re-add the obviously correct content root.